# Need help counting records for MVC Web App

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm just learning how to stray from the code that Visual Studio produces (MVC Entity Framework). I have a View that displays the contents of a Contact table. I have another page that I want to count the records. (obviously this is a over simplification). I have a model and controller for the "Contact" table. I have a model and a controller for the "Stats" but I am getting all sorts of mixed results from various tutorials and questions answered. Can someone help walk me through how I can populate the count on the "Stats" page? I'll be honest, I've only been working at this a week and even having a hard time declaring variables.

Here's my Contacts Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
namespace BasicContacts.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Intake Date")]
        public string DateIntake { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's my Contacts Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BasicContacts.Models;

namespace BasicContacts.Controllers
{
    public class CtController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: /Ct/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Contacts.ToList());
        }

        // GET: /Ct/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contact);
        }

        // GET: /Ct/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Ct/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ContactID,DateIntake,NameFirst")] Contact contact)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(contact);
        }

        // GET: /Ct/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contact);
        }

        // POST: /Ct/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ContactID,DateIntake,NameFirst")] Contact contact)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(contact);
        }

        // GET: /Ct/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contact);
        }

        // POST: /Ct/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
            db.Contacts.Remove(contact);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Contacts Index Page:

```
@model IEnumerable<BasicContacts.Models.Contact>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateIntake)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NameFirst)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateIntake)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameFirst)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ContactID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ContactID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ContactID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Obviously there is a shared Layout page.

So how would I create a "Stats" Model and Controller in Visual Studio and what should be in it to be able to display a SQL query that counts the records in "Contacts?" And as a bonus if I could use the MVC html helpers that seems most consistent with the current architecture.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `db.Contacts.Count()`?

Comment: Are you looking for `Total Contacts: @Model.Count()` that you want to display in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like to do any calculations in the view (personal preference).

I do all my counts/aggregations/sums/percentages in my controller action Stats and create a model that contains properties for each statistic that I want to display.

I then create my stats view with html helpers that display these model properties within the view.

Let me know if that doesn't make sense.  HTH

Comment: Thanks. That answers how you might go about doing it. Forgive my ignorance, but i don't know what that code looks like. Where does that go in my CtController? Where does it go in the model or what explicit steps do I take to create that model?
Thanks.